# Adjust menu bar buttons' highlighter when scrollling the webpage

Tags: javascript, css, menu

Take a look at https://www.simple.com website.  See the way menu (& submenu) works when you scroll the webpage.

Does anyone know what it's called or know how it works?  I'm trying to find a example or plug that can do this.

Thanks...

Comment: Did anyone tried scrolling down the webpage on the right side and watch the animate effect of the navigator bar menu at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to delete the question as there's no answer to what I'm looking for and there's no need to leave behind an unanswered post 2 years from now.

Answer (score 0):

It is called **fixed navigation bar** and here is a great tutorial

http://www.fuelyourcreativity.com/how-to-create-a-fixed-navigation-bar-for-your-website/

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple using jquery scroll() event handler.

You can bind it using following code

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
//your code goes here
}
```

read more at http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Answer (score 0):

It's just a simple anchor tag they've used along with some jQuery. A quick example here for you.

1. Create your links as normal `<a href="#blog">Blog</a>`. This creates an anchor to move to your blog section.
2. Add a class to your  element so it's now like: `<a href="#blog" class="scroll">Blog</a>`
3. Next, add the jQuery code below to your page.

Don't forget to include the jQuery library..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    });

});
```